# Segmentation Fault (core dump) when using getchar() in C?

Tags: c

I am writing a program for a class, and need to recieve a string from standard input. I am using getchar(), but when I run the program it seems to produce the segmentation fault error when encountering the loop with getchar() in it. Here's my code:

(An example input would be: 5, 14:09:01, 1, 1013)

```
int i, j;
int continueInput = 1;
/* initialize health data records for each patient */

for( i=0; i < MAXPATIENTS; i++ ){
    record[i].id = i + 1;
    for( j=0; j < MAXTYPES; j++ ){
        record[i].buffer[j].start = 0;
        record[i].buffer[j].end = 0;
    }
}
printf("Welcome to the Health Monitoring System\n\n");

while(continueInput == 1){
    i = 0;
    int c;
    char input[50];
    while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF){
        input[i++] = c;
    }
    if(c == EOF){
        continueInput = 0;
        continue;
    }
    else{
        input[i] = '\0';
        int length = i;
        int commaCount = 0;
        int patientNumber, command, value;
        char time[9], valueString[6];
        int timeCount = 0, valueCount = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < length; i++){
            if(input[i] == ','){
                commaCount++;
            }
            if(commaCount == 0){
                patientNumber = atoi(input[i]);
            }
            else if(input[i] == ' '){
                /*do nothing*/
                continue;
            }
            else if(commaCount == 1){
                time[timeCount] = input[i];
                timeCount++;
            }
            else if(commaCount == 2){
                command = atoi(input[i]);
            }
            else if(commaCount == 3){
                valueString[valueCount] = input[i];
                valueCount++;
            }
        }
        valueString[valueCount + 1] = '\0';
        time[timeCount + 1] = '\0';
        switch(command){
            case 1:
            {
                double temp = atof(valueString);
                temp = temp / 10;
                printf("%s: Temperature for Patient ID = %d is %f", time, patientNumber, temp);
            }
            case 2:
            {
                int heartRate = atoi(valueString);
                printf("%s: Heart Rate for Patient id = %d is %d", time, patientNumber, heartRate);
            }
            case 3:
            {
                int sPressure = atoi(valueString);
                printf("%s: Systolic Pressure for Patient id = %d is %d", time, patientNumber, sPressure);
            }
            case 4:
            {
                int dPressure = atoi(valueString);
                printf("%s: Diastolic Pressure for Patient id = %d is %d", time, patientNumber, dPressure);
            }
            case 5:
            {
                int rate = atoi(valueString);
                printf("%s: Respiration Rate for Patient id = %d is %d", time, patientNumber, rate);
            }
            case 6:
            {
                printf("%s: Print command entered for Patient id = %d", time, patientNumber);
            }
        }
    }
}       
printf("\nEnd of Input\n");
```

}

```
#define MAXPATIENTS 5
#define MAXREADINGS 10
#define MAXTYPES 5
#define MAXTIME 8

/* One health type reading: timestamp + actual value */
typedef struct{
    char timestamp[MAXTIME+1];
    int value;
}Element;

/* Circular buffer of health type readings */
typedef struct{
    int start;  /* index of oldest reading */
    int end;    /* index of most current reading */
    Element reading[MAXREADINGS];
}CircularBuffer;

/* Patient's health chart: ID + multiple health type readings */
typedef struct{
    int id;
    CircularBuffer buffer[MAXTYPES];
}Chart;
```

Comment: Is it possible that there are lines of input with more than 50 characters?

Comment: Also, I don't think you're parsing `patientNumber` correctly when the first field has a number larger than 10.

Comment: And the lines of code that try to null terminate `valueString` and `time` put the null character one element beyond where they should, so there will be a garbage character at the end of those strings.  It might pay to step through this with a debugger and/or throw in some debugging output.

Comment: Both of these `valueString[valueCount + 1] = '\0'`, and `time[timeCount + 1] = '\0';`, should **not** be +1'ing their termination. Their indexes are already where the terminator needs to be because you set the value and incremented the index variable during parsing. It should be `valueString[valueCount] = 0;` etc. Edit: Sorry Michael, I just now saw your second comment.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys. I fixed the valueString and time index problem, but am still getting the error. The inputs are always formated in a specific way so having too many characters shouldn't be the error. I changed the array size to 100 just to make sure and still got the same error. I put a print statement in the getchar() while loop and it never prints, but everything before that loop prints, which is why I think somehow that loop is the source of the problem.

Comment: Also as a quick side note, patientNumber cannot be greater than 5

Comment: Maybe you should post a small complete program with the problem (and one or two lines of data).  Now I'm wondering what the `record` array looks like and its elements' members.

Comment: Ok I added the structs and an example input at the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lines of code calling `atoi()` are passing a character as an argument when they should pass a pointer.  Change

```
patientNumber = atoi(input[i]);
```

to

```
patientNumber = atoi(&input[i]);
```

Similarly for the the `command = atoi(input[i]);` line.

I would have thought the compiler would issue a diagnostic for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
char input[50];
while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF){
    input[i++] = c;
}
```

I'm not sure if this is your bug or not, but if you type more than 50 chars (followed by a '\n'), you'll corrupt the stack (and most likely crash).

Suggested workaround:

```
input[0] = '\0';
const int maxlen = sizeof(input)/sizeof(input[0]);
while (i < (maxlen-1))
{
    c = getchar();
    if ((c == '\n') || (c == EOF))
    {
        break;
    }
    input[i] = ch;
    input[i+1] = '\0';
    i++;
}
```